# integration of polynomial p(x)/Q(x)

Tags: calculus

How can we integrate

$$\frac{a+bx^{n-1}}{cx - d x^n}$$

where n is any real no,

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you e.g. know how to integrate $1/(x^2-1)$ using the partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: The numerator is *sort of* derivative of the numerator. At least you can split it into a trivially integrable part that becomes $A\ln(cx-dx^n)$ with $A$ determined by polynomial division, plus an integral $B\int\frac{dx}{cx-dx^n}$.

Comment: @ Jik we can integrate it by partial fraction but in my question n is unknown so i can't get its partial fraction...

Comment: @ABC: Of course, if there's no evidence the OP has given the question any thought, why should *I* start thinking about it? I would rarely go to a colleague and just assign an interesting problem; such a discussion usually begins with "I've already thought about the obvious things, and they don't work because ___". (aside: I had already decided not to downvote this question before I started reading the comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it as $$\frac{a+bx^{n-1}}{cx - d x^n}=\frac{1}{c d (n-1)}\left(\frac{a d n+b c}{x}-\frac{(a d+b c)(c-ndx^{n-1})}{(c x-d x^n)}\right)$$

Comment: @ ABC how to  get the above partial fraction...

Comment: You want to subtract $A\frac{c-ndx^{n-1}}{cx-dx^n}$ for some constant $A$. Such that no term depending on $n$ remains. Subtract that, impose that condition and you get the constant $A$, what remains is the other term with the $B\frac{1}{x}$. It is also what *orion* was telling you.